# Airflow: is there a way to "clear all failed runs"?

Tags: airflow

In my Airflow GUI I see:

[image]

The large number of failed runs are due to an issue importing a particular python module. Is there a way to "retry all" on these? What I want essentially is to be able to "clear existing tasks" on all of these (causing the scheduler to rerun).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete in batch from UI.

Browse -> Task Instances
[image]

filter state failed
[image]

Now select the filter result and clear it

[image]

Note: Make sure you select only the desired one before clearing

The similar process you follow for clearing dagrun also :)

Comment: Thank you! In this case I manually restarted them all but will try next time!